# Set uniforms using uniform[1234][uif] in a WebGL program: is the vector version [v] better in any regard?

Tags: javascript, performance, glsl, webgl

Is there any significant advantage/disadvantage with setting a WebGL program's uniforms using the `uniform[1234][uif][v]` with an array like type instead of just using `uniform[1234][uif]` + spreading the arguments eg. :

```js
gl.uniform3f (location, v0, v1, v2);   // GLSL type: vec3
// vs
gl.uniform3fv(location, [v0, v1, v2]); // GLSL type: vec3 (or vec3[] array)
```

Obviously setting aside the fact that one version of the method handles arrays.

I am looking for considerations in term of performance, readability and overall best practices.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array version is slightly slower *by itself*. Quoting [WebGL insights](http://webglinsights.com) (page 19),

> For example, comparing 
>   `uniform4f` to `uniform4fv` instead of `uniform1f`, we 
>   found that `uniform4fv` is slower than `uniform4f` in all 
>   browsers that we tried, despite taking as few parameters as 
>   `uniform1f` does. This is due to `uniform4fv` having inherently more work to do than `uniform4f`, since it can handle 
>   arbitrary uniform array uploads.

Basically, having to check whether the input is an array (and then check its element types), typed array, etc loses the performance gained from passing fewer parameters.

However, this mostly means that you should use whichever matches your data, since unpacking an existing array could outweigh the benefits (feel free to test it though).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just do whatever you want. I mean it's really hard to suggest which is better as it depends too much on your personal coding preferences.

Let's say you make a vector like this

```
 const v = {x: 1, y: 2, z: 3}
```

Now when it comes time to use it with `gl.uniform` you could do either of these

```
 gl.uniform3f(loc, v.x, v.y, v.z);
 gl.uniform3fv(loc, [v.x, v.y, v.z]);
```

In that case the first is better because the second is creating a new array every time that line is executed.

On the other hand if you create a vector like this

```
 const v = [1, 2, 3];
```

Then

```
 gl.uniform3f(loc, v[0], v[1], v[2]);
 gl.uniform3fv(loc, v);
```

Clearly the second is better.

With ES5 you have one more option which is

```
 gl.uniform3f(loc, ...v);
```

I don't know if that's faster or slower than `gl.uinform3fv(loc, v)`. I suspect it's slower today but might be the same speed in the future. Since you have `gl.uinform3fv` there's really no reason to use that style. It can be useful for other functions though that don't have a format that takes an array. Examples

```
 const color = [1, 0, 0, 1];

 gl.clearColor(...color);
```

Comment: Thanks! So it seems program/app's design will dictate the use of one or the other. Ultimately I guess it depends on the WebGL implementation by the browser. At this point, it might be premature optimisation.